# Treelist data to navigation

Tags: cakephp, tree, navigation, nav, treelist

I'm trying to do a navigation. I have treelist for products.

```
Products
-product A
 --product A.1
 --product A.2
  ---product A.2.1
-product B
 --product B.1
```

How can i show in my navigation only the parent. For example,

```
Products
-product A
-product B
```

I use cakephp 3.0. I make this treelist based on the tutorial blog.Can anyone help me?

This is my controller.

```
   public function index()
    {
        $products = $this->Products->find()
            ->order(['lft' => 'ASC']);
        $this->set(compact('products'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['products']);
    }
```

Comment: explain: you liwant to filter your `find('treeList')` call showing only the first level? Then add `->where(['parent_id' => $root_id])` and $root_id is the id of root of your tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's suppose you don't have a root node in your tree.

I understand you want to retrieve all and just the nodes that are at the firt level. In this case you are looking for the nodes who have a NULL parent_id

```
$products = $this->Products->find('treeList')
    ->where(['parent_id IS NULL']);
```

instead if you have a root node which id is i.e. 1

```
$root_id = 1;
$products = $this->Products->find('treeList')
    ->where(['parent_id' => $root_id ]);
```

Comment: i got an internal error. i want my parent_id is null.

Comment: Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: I mean: turn debug mode on and show what kind of error you are facing

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template\Products\index.ctp, line 47] .  This is line 47 : `<td><?= $product->id ?></td>`

Comment: well, as you can see the error is in the view file (index.ctp) and not in the controller. So you are facing some other issue

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help.